# Multiple screens plus HDTV, can't get all 3 working

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Bought a new PC on the weekend and installed the ATI Radeon 4350 card from the old computer. Running 64-bit Windows 7. Came with Intel HD 4600.

So the old computer had 2 Dell monitors connected in the office with the Samsung HDTV in the lounge, all connected at once. We used Catalyst control center to switch the displays around depending on what we were doing.

If the TV was on, so we could watch a movie from the hard drive, we'd duplicate screen one (Dell / main desktop) onto the HTDV (screen 3) and screen 2 (Dell) would remain the extended desktop.

Issue: I can only get 2 screens active at once. At present, screen plus HTDV is on with HDTV showing what I should expect to see on the my screen 2 (dell), which is blank. Thus screen one is extending onto screen 3. My aim is for either screen 1 to extend to screen 2, and duplicate either one onto screen 3, HDTV.

Can anyone guide me in very simple terms/steps as I am a complete novice?

NB. The Catalyst Control Center looks totally different to the one on the previous PC. Unsure why...I uninstalled the new look CCC and reinstalled 'old' one from disk, but it still came up with the new version.

Comment: Does your BIOS allow you to use both discreet and internal GPU at the same time? I've seen cheap mobos where they only allow 1 card, which could be the reason why you can only activate 2 screens. If this is the case, you could try a BIOS update, but I'm not sure that would help.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to expand your desktop over screen 1 and 2 and then duplicate either of them onto the HDTV.

I know you say that you are used to the Catalyst Control Center, but I would suggest for these simple things to use the built in windows "Screen Resolution" control panel.

To duplicate a desktop onto your HDTV do the following:

1. Right click on the desktop and select "Screen Resolution"
2. Select the display you want to duplicate (lets say screen 1)
3. In the multiple display drop down select "Duplicate desktop on 1 and 3" like this:
   [image: duplicating a screen in windows]
4. Screen nr 2 should have the "Extend desktop to this display" selected.

You might have to fiddle around and activate/deactivate some screens if your graphics card only can handle two at the time, but once 1 and 3 are cloned, they count as one screen and screen 2 can be activated again.